# Simulating data in R

Tags: r

For part of my statistics assignment I have to study the distribution of the mean of a Poisson distribution. I'm asked to create a function poi_bar with inputs n, N, lambda where we have a vector of length N, and each individual entry in the vector is equal to the mean of n numbers chosen on a Poisson distribution with lambda = lambda.

I've tried a dozen things and searched the internet for hours and have found nothing that tells me how to do this. The closest I was able to get was when I defined the function like this:

```
 poi_bar = function(n, N, lambda) {

    V = rep(c(mean(rpois(n, lambda = lambda))), times = N)

    return(V)
 }
```

To test if this really worked, I tried n = 8, N = 25, lambda = 17, and the result was this:

```
 poi_bar(8,25,17)

 [1] 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375

 [9] 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375

 [17] 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375 18.375

 [25] 18.375
```

But I want the samples to be different, not just repeat one twenty-five times.

Comment: This is an R question not RStudio related. I will edit the question title.

Comment: See the code I added to the answer. It makes it more complete, with an alternative solution meant for speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `replicate`, not `rep`.

```
poi_bar <- function(n, N, lambda) {
  V <- replicate(N, mean(rpois(n, lambda = lambda)))
  V
}

set.seed(1234)
poi_bar(8, 25, 17)
```

**Edit.**
Though the answer was already accepted, I realized that there is a better, faster way of doing the same.
Functions `colMeans` and `rowMeans` are considerably faster than repeated applications of `mean`, so what follows checks whether that is true in this use case.

Note that the function `poi_bar` is the same as above but in order to make the timings fair I have rewritten it as a one-liner. The original is more clear.

```
poi_bar = function(n, N, lambda) {
  replicate(N, mean(rpois(n, lambda = lambda)))
}

poi_bar2 = function(n, N, lambda) {
  colMeans(replicate(N, rpois(n, lambda = lambda)))
}
```

Now test them and see that the results are identical.

```
set.seed(1234)
p <- poi_bar(8, 2500, 17)

set.seed(1234)
p2 <- poi_bar2(8, 2500, 17)

identical(p, p2)
#[1] TRUE
```

And the timings. I will use two CRAN packages, `microbenchmark` and `ggplot2` to plot the results.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  v1 = poi_bar(8, 2500, 17), 
  v2 = poi_bar2(8, 2500, 17)
  )
print(mb)
autoplot(mb)
```

[image]